# Creating Image from Pixel Values

Tags: java, image, text, rgb, pixel

In java...I have an integer array of RGB pixels, means **output** of my program is as follows:
'

```
Pixel 1: 255 200 191 231
Pixel 2: 255 237 028 036
Pixel 3: 255 034 177 076
Pixel 4: 255 085 140 066
Pixel 5: 255 200 191 231
Pixel 6: 255 237 028 036
Pixel 7: 255 231 188 167
Pixel 8: 255 237 028 036
Pixel 9: 255 237 028 036
Pixel 10: 255 063 072 204
Pixel 11: 255 226 125 144
Pixel 12: 255 063 072 204
Pixel 13: 255 200 191 231
Pixel 14: 255 062 187 099
Pixel 15: 255 255 127 039
Pixel 16: 255 255 127 039
Pixel 17: 255 200 191 231
Pixel 18: 255 212 177 189
Pixel 19: 255 063 072 204
Pixel 20: 255 040 158 100
Pixel 21: 255 034 177 076
Pixel 22: 255 237 028 036
Pixel 23: 255 248 253 249
Pixel 24: 255 165 169 231
Pixel 25: 255 200 191 231
```

How can I create image of size 5 x 5 image using the above data...?'

Comment: This question has been cross-posted by the original poster to many sites and forum on the internet. To the original poster: you've been asked let all sites know of cross-posts and yet you still refuse to follow this basic courtesy. Why?

Comment: you're getting these data as byte array or string line by line or somehow else?

Comment: Put RGB values in an integer array, in i % 3 parts. Create an instance of BufferedImage and WritableRaster, assign the buffimage raster to newly created one. Set the pixel of raster, and you're done basically.

Comment: I have mentioned it on the sites...'

Comment: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/file-i-o-other-i-o-streams/17794-conversion-any-image-file-text-file-java-2.html

Comment: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/63175-conversion-any-image-file-text-file-java.html

Comment: I was unaware of other site posts if they have to be posted here'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `BufferedImage`
getting the `Graphics/Graphics2D` object from the BufferedImage
and painting with the `Graphics` object the pixels.

The BufferedImage can be stored as a File with `ImageIO` or displayed in an Own `Component/JComponent`

A Bit Pseudo code

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(5,5,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
while(i < 25){
  g.setColor(new Color(See Api for more details on how to create a Color);
  g.drawRect(i/5, i%5, 1,1);
}
```

Now you have a BufferdImage to be saved with ImageIO

```
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File(output));
```

Or get a New JComponent and overwrite its paint Method. There are plenty resources for this task.