# How to create image from RGB values which have been saved in .txt

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreateImage extends Component{

    BufferedImage img;

    int pixel = 265*190;
    int steg = 3;
    int p,s;
    int [][] rgb_steg = new int [pixel][steg];



     public CreateImage()throws Exception{


        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("cover-fruits.jpg"));
        }catch (IOException e){

        }



        File f = new File("stego_rgb.txt");
        if(!(f.exists())){
            System.out.println("Sorry file are not exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        String data = null;
        int rgb = 0;
        int rgb1 = 0;
        p=0;


        while(in.hasNextInt()){
            data = in.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data," ");
            for(s=0;s<steg;s++){
                rgb = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                rgb_steg[p][s] = rgb;
                rgb1 = rgb_steg[p][s];
            }
            p++;


        }




         for(int y = 0 ; y <img.getHeight() ; y++){
               for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth() ; x++){
                   img.setRGB(x, y, rgb1);
               }
           }





    File output = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(img , "png", output);

    img  = ImageIO.read(new File("saved.png"));



    }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
});

        f.add(new CreateImage());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }





}
```

I'm trying to read the RGB values from .txt and create image.But I didnt manage to do it.
I have some ideas from [Creating Image from Pixel Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546559/creating-image-from-pixel-values)
but still couldnt get it.
Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: How do you know the width/height of the image in the text field?

Comment: i set the width/height of the image only to test.
actually we can get the width/height of the image by using .getheight() and .getWidth()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that create an image with hardcoded values. Shouldn't be too hard to make the population of the array values dynamic.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageFromArray2 extends JFrame
{
    int width = 50;
    int height = 50;
    int imageSize = width * height * 3;

    public ImageFromArray2()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( panel );
        int[] pixels = new int[imageSize];

        //  Create Red Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 255;
            pixels[i+1] = 0;
            pixels[i+2] = 0;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Green Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0;
            pixels[i+1] = 255;
            pixels[i+2] = 0;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Blue Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0;
            pixels[i+1] = 0;
            pixels[i+2] = 255;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Cyan Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i += 3)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0;
            pixels[i+1] = 255;
            pixels[i+2] = 255;
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

    }

    private JLabel createImageLabel(int[] pixels)
    {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
        raster.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
        JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(image) );
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new ImageFromArray2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

It uses a simple array but you need 3 slots to specify the RGB values for each pixel.

Comment: camickr,I havent got answer to my question, and cannot bring up my question as new, its now too down the list, please help me here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220399/cannot-instantiate-a-class-using-a-button

Comment: camickr, tenx for the code.it help me.
actually i'm having problem to read RGB values from .txt
I wish to read the rgb.txt and create the image from that values.

Comment: `actually i'm having problem to read RGB values from .txt` - @noobprogrammer, so post your `SSCCE` that show how you read the file and add the integer values to the array.